# symfony 3 session flashdata not working

Tags: symfony

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
```

...

```
public function __construct()
{
    //echo ini_get('session.auto_start'); die;

    $this->session = new Session();


/**
 * @Route("/", name="registration_index")
 * @Route("/user/registration", name="registration")
 * @Method("GET")
 */
public function indexAction()
{

    //$this->session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');

    $errors = $this->session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array());

    print_r($errors);

    return $this->render('registration.html.twig', ['errors' => $errors]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/user/registration", name="post_registration")
 * @Method("POST")      
 * @return mixed
 */
public function postAction()
{

    //$this->session->getFlashBag()->add('errors', 'hahaha');

    $this->session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile updated');


    return $this->redirectToRoute('registration');
}
```

I will want to display error messages near input fields if there is registration failure. Trying to use session flashdata.

When user goes to postAction method, he is redirected to indexAction. But

```
print_r($errors);
```

prints empty array. Why is that? Without redirect - it works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not symfony problem, but php server problem. Even code examples from php manual without symfony did not work.

I was running server like this:

php -S 0.0.0.0:8000

and for some reasons the session did not work on it.

When I started using nginx server, session started working.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you are not using symfony Forms to get this functionality? Symfony Forms are perfect for registration pages. 
By the way, if you are doing this in a controller then you don't need the constructor method. Instead get the session from Request->getSession()

Comment: Its because I have heard from guy who has worked with symfony 2.x that synfony forms are bad.

Comment: Did the guy give reasons? So is this a controller? If it extends the symfony controller you can do $this->addFlash();

Comment: I did not even ask the reasons, because to understand, I guess I need to first see the examples of code. And I believe him, because he is good programmer. This is controller extending Controller class.

Comment: Request->getSession() - does not have getFlashBag() method .

Comment: If its in the controller you can just do $this->addFlash() see here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that WebCookie sais in his comment: In the controller please use `$this->addFlash()` if your need to add a flash message within a controller.

Notice you can also use session service like this: `$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add()`

For further informations [Flash messages](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages).